# SCrypt - Hashing and comparing password on browser

Tags: javascript, passwords, scrypt

Is there any JS library that support hashing and comparing `SCrypt-based` passwords like [node-scrypt](https://github.com/barrysteyn/node-scrypt)?

Answer (score 0):

i know about this one this is easy to use and documentation is very easy check it

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/password-hash
```